# Angular $http call throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angular to call the google map api service. But even after wrapping it with `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` I am getting Uncaught

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token : error.

```js
getResult: function (location) {
    var placeAPIURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=" + location + "&key=abcd123&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

    return $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
        dataType: "JSONP",
        url: placeAPIURL
    }).success(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    }).error(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Couple of things I have tried:

1. $http.jsonp ->  throws CORS error
2. passed json_callback=JSON_CALLBACK -> no change

Any idea what I am missing

Comment: one more thing that i observe:
in the network tab: the JSON_CALLBACK gets automatically changed to callback=angular.callbacks._1. Not sure why is this happening. So the request looks something like this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=boston&key=abcd123&json_callback=angular.callbacks._1

Comment: jsonp will never throw a CORS error.